# DbSet variable table name

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, reflection, entity-framework-core

I am writing an application where I need to abstract the DbSet table name.
Instead of calling **_db.Activities.ToList()** (where Activity is a table in Sql) the code below will work for any variable table input.

Now I wanted to use **.Where(),.OrderBy(),.FromSqlRaw()** and other methods on top of the existing code.

How can I write _db.Activities.FromSqlRaw(...) for example, with a variable table name, just like it is doing for the GetAll method.

This is my DbSet for Activity

```
public virtual DbSet<Activity> Activities { get; set; } = null!;
```

This is the method to get all records from a variable table

```
public dynamic GetAll(string Table)
        {
            var curEntityPI = _db.GetType().GetProperty(Table);
            var curEntityType = curEntityPI.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First();
            // Getting Set<T> method
            var method = _db.GetType().GetMember("Set").Cast<MethodInfo>().Where(x => x.IsGenericMethodDefinition).FirstOrDefault();
            // Making Set<SomeRealCrmObject>() method
            var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(curEntityType);
            // invoking Setmethod into invokeSet 
            dynamic invokeSet = genericMethod.Invoke(_db, null);
            // invoking ToList method from Set<> invokeSet 
            return Enumerable.ToList(invokeSet); 
        }
```

The general idea comes from this post

[reflection-linq-dbset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253017/reflection-linq-dbset)

Comment: Is this really what you need, though? What are your goals? Are you sure you're not falling in an XY-problem?

Comment: Discussion of [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: C# is a language of types. Using `dynamic` is a very bad idea for performance and code correctness. Once you have the result of a query on an unknown table with unknown fields, what do you intend to do with it?

Comment: *need to abstract the DbSet table name* - slippery slope

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, I have a component in a blazor server that I want to be available to the entire application which access the db. At the moment I have a huge switch statement making the same exact call for different tables. This abstraction would reduce it to 1 line. I am sure if this is the correct approach though

Comment: @NetMage for each page, when the dynamic model is returned, it gets written to that page's specific model so it can be used. Since the dynamic comes from a sql call, I know from which table it comes from and it gets the correct structure of the page model. So it is not unknown. I have 1 model for each table on my sql server following their exact same structure.

Comment: Could you edit your question and include those details (abbreviated) so we can see how it looks like right now before this dynamic stuff? There might be better abstractions (such as using a generic `T` and then chaining the rest of the calls)

Answer (score 1):

Define return type of method as **List< dynamic>** instead of **dynamic**

```
public List<dynamic> GetAll(string Table)  
{
    //your code...
    return Enumerable.ToList(invokeSet); 
}
```

Activity Class:

```
public class Activity
{
    public int Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

So, you can use all methods of List type

```
var activityList = GetAll("Activities");
var filteredList = activities.Where(x => x.Field1 > 1);
var orderedList = filteredList.OrderBy(x => x.Field2);
```

Comment: Hi, @iemere. There are two problems with that, first that would not work for FromSqlRaw and second it would return the whole model and the filter would happen afterwards, which would not be ideal.